# 国家 vs. 国, when can 国 be used alone?

Tags: mandarin, grammar

In the Chinese book for beginners by Bellassen, it is stated that 国 cannot be used alone: it doesn't have a meaning on its own, and thus the word country/fatherland is 国家 and not 国.

However... I am surprised by the question 你是哪国人? (still in Bellassen's book). Would it be possible to ask 你是哪国家人吗? Are there other uses where 国 can be used alone, while still meaning country?

**edit:**  the word country/fatherland is indeed 国家 as stated in the answer below, and not 家国 as I first wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean 国家 instead of 家国. 家国 doesn't exist.

你是哪国家人吗  is not correct (nor is 你是哪国家人), but you can say 你是哪国家的人 or 你是哪国家的 (meaning: from which country are you).

In 你是哪国人, 国 is not really  on its own. You can treat 哪国人 as a unit (which is a short form for 哪国家的人).

In oral Chinese 国 is seldomly used on its own (but every character however has a meaning, and 国 on its own also means country), but is used in for example 国内 (inside this country, typically used to mean within China, 内 means inside) or 国旗 (national flag, 旗 means flag). The list of such examples is long.

Comment: Did you mean "In oral Chinese 国 is seldomly used on its own?"

Comment: In linguistics, 国 is what is known as a [bound morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_morpheme).  It carries grammatical meaning, but does not exist independently as a standalone word. Note that you may still see 国 as a standalone word in written language sometimes.  This may be sometimes employed to give the writing a "classical" feel, since 国 in [Classical Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Chinese) was not a bound morpheme.

Comment: @Claw, is there a "degree of bound"? Compared to the morphemes that can never be used alone (e.g. 们), 国 doesn't seem completely bound to me, as `国与国之间` sounds valid but not a bit "classical". Another example is in colloquial lines like `天国就是天上的国`.

Comment: @Claw Why aren't you on [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)? :)

Comment: @NS.X.: I don't know much about the "degree of bound" of 国, but I suppose it's not unreasonable to think that degrees may exist as particular words [fossilize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossilization_%28linguistics%29) into bound morphemes.  That being said, your first example uses 与, which is typically a Classical Chinese conjunction and in modern Mandarin is considered more formal than the usual 和.  In addition, I would posit that 国 is actually bound to 国与国, which is a rather idiomatic phrase which only has a few limited variations, such as 国与民.

Comment: @NS.X.: Concerning your second example, while comprehensible, 天国就是天上的国 seems somewhat incomplete to me when spoken aloud.  Various speakers may disagree, but I feel that 天国就是天上的国度 sounds much more natural orally.

Comment: 家国 is not so common as 国家, but it does exist. It means home and the country or just country. It often appears on classical Chinese poetries.

Comment: @Alenanno: The current participants on that exchange are much more knowledgeable than me in linguistics and usually provide much better answers, so I've been happy to simply lurk for now.

Comment: @Claw It's up to you, of course. I don't want to force anyone, but you don't need to be a super-expert to be there. :D

Answer (score 3):

When used alone (like in a noun phrase), `国家` and `国` are interchangeable, but there is a idiomatic tendency to use a word's multi-character form to make the sentence flow more "stable" (I am sure there is a concept/terminology for this but I don't know).

For example, `一个国家`, as a noun phrase, sounds stable and complete. `一个国` is not wrong but doesn't sound stable like something should follow. If you say `一个国，一个家，一个民族` then the rhythm is satisfied and the phrase is now complete. When there are more and more characters in a phrase, the stability requirement of each single word is less important, so `国与国之间` and `国家与国家之间` both sound natural.

In words that contains `国` (e.g. `国旗`), you can't replace it with `国家` (i.e. `国家旗` is not a word) simply because words are not free form. `哪国人` can be seen as a word (as opposed to phrase) meaning `哪个国家的人`.

Comment: i really like your explanation. I didn't know the concept of rythmical stability in Chinese.

Comment: @StephaneRolland, after reading Claw's comment I realized my answer was merely superficial observation and the root explanation should be the 'bound morpheme' concept.

Comment: @NS.X.: The word you were looking for is [prosody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_%28linguistics%29).  You're not incorrect; prosody does play a role in whether speakers choose a polysyllabic word over a monosyllabic one, and it probably did play a role in the formation of bound morphemes in modern Mandarin (though the loss of the final consonants _-p -t -k -m_ from Middle Chinese played a much larger role).  _Chinese: A Comprehensive Grammar_ by Yip Po-Ching has a full chapter devoted to prosody in modern Mandarin.

Answer (score 0):

国 is an abbreviation for 国家. The latter loosely translates to "national family."

If you were talking about a country as a concept, you'd say"一个国家."

But if you were talking about specific countries, you'd use 国as an "abbreviation" after a specifier:

德 国, "Deutschland," or Germany.
Or 法国, France.